# How can we set different height for particular UITabBarItem's image in UITabBar?

Tags: ios, swift, uitabbarcontroller, uitabbaritem

[image]

I have an image for middle `UITabBarItem` which should start from the bottom and align with existing `UITabBar`. How can I change the height of `UITabBarItem` for middle item?

Comment: check this https://github.com/v-braun/VBRRollingPit

Answer (score 0):

To achieve this you need to use your custom TabBarView. It is a simple view, that pinned to the bottom. Design like you want and that's all! This is the best way without issues with working default TabBar.

every "not default looking" tab bar - it is custom